# Counting instances in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

At my school, we have a Google Form for recording classroom discipline. The form generates the standard spreadsheet.  I want a list of how many times each unique student has received a disciplinary action. It would be great if it can be broken down by Discipline (i.e., how many Silent Lunches and PE Detentions John Doe gets) but even just something that says `John Doe, 6` is great.

I would like this information in either a separate worksheet/table or at least in a new column. I've looked and found a lot of information about count function, queries, arrays, etc., but I can't tweak the parameters of what I've found to the point where I get what I need.

[image: WA67540 question example]

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet is to allow a pivot table to construct the options for you (though could be achieved with formulae in a matrix). Please try selecting your data and Data, Pivot table report..., with `Student Name` for Rows, `Discipline` for Columns and Summarise by: COUNTA Discipline.